# How to divide up Nuget packages based on Version in Nuget Server

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-server

So we are having a Nuget server that we push our product nuget packages to. 
Currently we are using semantic versioning to version our packages, and we want to be able to push older version fixes as a patch version change to the package while still have newer version packages on the server.

For example, we are currently at v 2.5 of the product, we want to push a bug fix for version 2.4 as 2.4.1 and 2.5.1. This way we can test an environment that is running 2.4 by updating it to 2.4.1 without having to update it to the latest version of the product.

Is there a way to modify the nuget push command so we can still push it to the Nuget server?

How about modifying the Nuget server web.config?

We are currently using  [Klondike Nuget Server](https://github.com/themotleyfool/Klondike)

Comment: Just push it.  There's nothing in Nuget that prevents you from pushing out releases with lower version numbers than your highest current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuget by itself does not prevent you from pushing packages with lower versions. Are you running into any errors when you try to push a package with lower version?

Comment: I am, for some reason the push fails when I am trying to push lower version packages to the server, even though it goes through the same exact script to build and push the package. I guess I will double check and make sure I'm not making any stupid error that I didn't catch before.